# How to assign a value teamcity variable from msbuild command

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity

I have a msbuild step where I will parse the xml file and get some filtered data. I need to pass the filtered data to Teamcity. Could this be done by teamcity variable or any other way?

```
<Target Name="ParseXmlAndReturn" >
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath ="$(ResultDir)\xmlfile.xml"
         Query="<filter to get specific data from xml>">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="parsedxml"/>
</XmlPeek>
<Message Text="parsed xml is $(parsedxml)"/>
```

From the above task of msbuild, I need to pass parsedxml value to teamcity or assign a systemvariable to teamcity to the parsedvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Teamcity '[Build Script Interaction](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter)' documentation:

> By using a dedicated service message in your build script, you can
>   dynamically update some build parameters right from a build step, so
>   that the following build steps will run with a modified set of build
>   parameters.
>   `##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff']`

So change the message tack to something like

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[setParameter name='ParsedXML' value='$(parsedxml)']"/>
```